# Passing a List<T> and a bool

Tags: c#

What is the best way of passing both a `List<T>` and a `bool` as the returning value of a method? Right now I have this custom class called `BoolList` acting like a container but I was wondering if there is a better and/or more elegant way of doing it.

Comment: use a tuple<bool, List<T>> or use an out parameter

Comment: erm, with a type that composes of a `bool` and a `List<T>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Tuple<List<T>, bool>`

```
public Tuple<List<string>, bool> MethodName()
{
    return Tuple.Create(new List<string>(), true);
}
```

or make the `List<T>` `out` parameter and return `bool` as normal one (like `TryParse` methods do)

```
public bool MethodName(out List<string> results)
{
    results = new List<string>();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: @Strum, Its ok and quick but, don't you find the names `Item1` and `Item2` lack contextual meaning. If you already have a custom class `BoolList` which composes the required types, you could give the accessors names that convey additional context.

Answer (score 4):

Why not use a tuple?

http://www.dotnetperls.com/tuple

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536.aspx

Then you have a type-safe container without having to create a class.

```
    private Tuple<List<int>, bool> myMethod()
    {
        var myList = new List<int>();
        var myBool = true;

        return new Tuple<List<int>, bool>(myList, myBool);
    }
```

Comment: Instead of `return new Tuple<List<int>, bool>(myList, myBool);` you can also write `return Tuple.Create(myList, myBool);`. That's a little shorter. With a method call (`Create`) the type parameters can be inferred by the compiler, but with a `new` expression one has to specify them.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned here, you can use a tuple and that is a good solution. The only drawback being that you refer to the items in the tuple with the non-informative names Item1, Item2... If you are going to be returning the same types often or you will be passing the result around where descriptive properties improve readability, then the other (old-fashioned) way is to have a class (or struct as described further down in this answer) with the return types as properties and return an instance of the class. For example a class definition could be local to your current class.

```
public class EmployeeSearchResult
{
    public List<Employee> Employees{get;set;}
    public bool Success{get;set;}
}

private EmployeeSearchResult Search()
{
    var employeeSearchResult = new EmployeeSearchResult();
    employeeSearchResult.Employees = new List<Employee>();
    employeeSearchResult.SearchSuccess = true;
    return employeeSearchResult;
}
```

Since the return is often small and lightweight with a short lifespan a struct may be a better option than a class. However, be aware of when a struct is appropriate - as per [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017.aspx): -

> √ CONSIDER defining a struct instead of a class if instances of the
> type are small and commonly short-lived or are commonly embedded in
> other objects.
>
> X AVOID defining a struct unless the type has all of
> the following characteristics:
>
> - It logically represents a single value, similar to primitive types (int, double, etc.).
> - It has an instance size under 16 bytes.
> - It is immutable.
> - It will not have to be boxed frequently.

Comment: If you have more than a few items, I agree this is a better solution. I usually use a struct instead of a class, though.

Comment: That is a good point, as long as the usage adheres to the guidelines for using a struct. I will update my answer.